# How to add new user to external userstore(AD) in WSO2 Indentity Server 4.5?

Tags: active-directory, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to add users to backend AD.
However, if i specify the password, I always get 'Password does not meet the system requirements. Please try again.' (I can add user to AD with the same pwd on ad server)

Then i tried 'Ask password from user' and not specifying password. Creation faild with the following message:

> Could not add user test.com/testadd. Error is: Credential not valid. Credential must be a non null string with following format, null

While I'm sure the ad certificate is added to all keystores i can find.

So what can i do next?

here is my user-mgt.xml

```
<UserManager>
<Realm>
    <Configuration>
    <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                 <UserName>admin</UserName>
                 <Password>admin</Password>
            </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
        <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
    </Configuration>

<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
        <!-- .... -->
        <!-- I didn't change this part -->
</UserStoreManager>

<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager">
        <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
        <Property name="defaultRealmName">test.com</Property>
        <Property name="DomainName">test.com</Property>
        <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldaps://10.20.112.213:636</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionName">CN=Adaccount,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=com</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionPassword">password@123</Property>
        <Property name="UserSearchBase">CN=Users,DC=test,DC=com</Property>
        <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">person</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameAttribute">sAMAccountName</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=?))</Property>
        <Property name="ReadLDAPGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
        <Property name="GroupSearchBase">CN=Users,DC=test,DC=com</Property>
        <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">group</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
        <Property name="MembershipAttribute">memberOf</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=group)</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(cn=?))</Property>
        <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="Referral">follow</Property>
        <Property name="isADLDSRole">false</Property>
        <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
        <Property name="maxFailedLoginAttempt">0</Property>
    </UserStoreManager>
    <AuthorizationManager
        class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
        <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
    <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
    </AuthorizationManager>
</Realm>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there can be issue with regex pattern of password. According to your configuration regex pattern is not define in config. May be,  WSO2IS uses some default pattern. Please try to configure them and see... I could see following in default user-mgt.xml file.  Try to configure them and check.

```
        <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="ServicePasswordJavaRegEx">^[\\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="ServiceNameJavaRegEx">^[\\S]{2,30}/[\\S]{2,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
```

Comment: Thanks, the password validation passed, but I still can't create the user. In the log, I see LDAP error code 53(WILL_NOT_PERFORM). I've confirmed that the password is valid, and I'm accessing ad via LDAPS. Any idea why this error code appears?

Comment: Typically this is generated when you use not use LDAPS. Also it can be due that user which you are using to connect to LDAP is not having sufficient rights.  It means "CN=Adaccount,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=com" which is define by the connection name,  must have rights to create users and change passwords of them...  could you please verify it also